# Combinatorics: Amount of options for majority

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have $2n$ people. Then the amount of options to form a majority (e.g. in a commission) are

$ \binom{2n}{n+1} + \binom{2n}{n+2} + \cdots + \binom{2n}{2n}$

I want to prove, that this is equal to $\frac{1}{2} \left[ 2^{2n} - \binom{2n}{n} \right]$

But I'm stuck. I have the this formula: $ \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} = 2^n $

So I can say $ \binom{2n}{n+1} + \binom{2n}{n+2} + \cdots + \binom{2n}{n} = 2^{2n} - \left[ \binom{2n}{n} + \binom{2n}{n-1} + \cdots + \binom{2n}{n-n} \right] = 2^{2n} - \left[ \binom{2n}{0} + \binom{2n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{2n}{n} \right] $

But I can't see where to go from there, even when writing the binomial coefficients as $ \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} $

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: You don't want the combinatorial proof?  Other that subsets with exactly half the elements, we can pair a subset with its complement and exactly one of those two will be a majority.  But of course you can mimic that argument with the binomial coefficients if you really want to.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}$

Comment: @lulu What do you mean with combinatorial proof? Can you explain more what you mean by that?

Comment: @Hebol combinatorical proof means a proof based on logic not involving algebra...if you want a combinatorical proof too...you can ask that as a separate question:)

Comment: I sketched the combinatorial proof in my comments.  Divide the subsets in two collections...one collection consists of subsets with $n$ elements, the rest are the other cololection.  First has $\binom {2n}n$ elements.  The second has $2^n-\binom {2n}n$ elements.  Half of the second have more than $2n$ (since you can pair up the elements in the second collection, each with its complement, and exactly one member of each pair has more than $n$ element.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the property of binomial coefficients $$\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$$
$\implies \binom{2n}{n+1}=\binom{2n}{n-1}$

$\implies\binom{2n}{n+2}=\binom{2n}{n-2}$ and so on

---

Let $$A=\binom{2n}{n+1}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{2n}$$ Also
$$A=\binom{2n}{0}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{n-1}$$
So $$2A=2^{2n}-\binom{2n}{n}$$

Comment: Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 4):

By symmetry $\binom{2n}{k}=\binom{2n}{2n-k}$ for $k=0,\ldots,n-1.$
So the sum, call is $S$, you have is also equal to
$$
\binom{2n}{0}+\binom{2n}{1}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{n-1}.
$$
Now $2S+\binom{2n}{n}=2^{2n},$ does it.

Comment: Thank you! This answered the question!

Answer (score 3):

- There are $2^{2n}$ ways of selecting a subset to vote "Yes" and the rest "No".
- Of these, ${2n \choose n}$ are the number of ways to have equal "Yes" and "No" votes,
- leaving  $2^{2n}-{2n \choose n}$ possibilities with a decisive result,
- half of which have a majority voting "Yes", getting your result

(the other half of the possibilities would have a majority voting "No"; a particular subset of individuals with the majority would be double counted, once when voting "Yes" against the rest and once when voting "No" against the rest).

Comment: Thanks, that really explains the formulas shape very well!